# MySQL - Limit rows to fetch

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to edit my table so that I can only enter a maximum of 6 rows of data.

Is it possible to do this using phpmyadmin?

Comment: What is the "table size limit"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to review this article.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html

You try this mysql query

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MAX_ROWS=1000000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=nnn;
```